# How to use the parenthesis in the expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

[question]
Could you tell me how to create the appropriate expression tree?

[detail]
I created following query statically, and result is as expected.

```
// Datasource
    string[] dataSource = { "John", "Ken", "Mark", "Mary", "Tom" };

// Keyword for Search
    string[] keywords = { "o", "Mark", "Tom" };


    //LINQ Query (Static)
    var query = dataSource.AsQueryable().
    Where(item =>
   (item.ToLower().Contains(keywords[0].ToLower()) ||
   item.ToLower().Contains(keywords[1].ToLower())) &&
   item.ToLower().Contains(keywords[2].ToLower())).
    OrderByDescending(item => item);


//Result
// "Tom"
```

condition A || condition B && condition C

but I do not know how to code the following condition with expression tree

(condition A || condition B) && condition C

Does anyone tell me how to use the parethesis in the expression tree?
So far what I created the body for lambda expression is as follows which does not work well.

```
public static Expression GetContainsExpression(Expression parameter, string keyword, Expression curBody)
{

    var keywordValue = Expression.Constant(keyword, typeof(string));
      var newBody =
      Expression.Equal( Expression.Call(parameter, ToLower), Expression.Call(keywordValue, ToLower) );

    ///Connect curBody Expression and newBody Expression with "Or" e.s. ||   
    if (curBody != null)
    {
        if (keyword == "Tom")
        {
            return Expression.AndAlso(curBody, newBody);
        }

        else
        return Expression.OrElse(curBody, newBody);
    }
    return newBody;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are forcefully making it a complex scenario. What is the actual purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parethesis are created automaticaly. You can't avoid it. `Expression.OrElse`  or `Expression.AndAlso` takes an other expression for left and right and if they are combined expressions as `BinaryExpression` is they are wrapped in parethesis automatically.

Have a look at this code:

```
var paramX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool), "x");
var paramY = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool), "y");
var paramZ = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool), "z");
var expr = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.OrElse(paramX, paramY), paramZ);
```

If you call `expr.ToString()` you'll get `"((x OrElse y) AndAlso z)"`. Even the outer AndAlso-Expression is wrapped into parethesis. There is no way to remove them (as I know so far).

A small hint: You can call `ToString()` on every expression and it will return the created code. Knowing this makes it easier to create dynamic expressions because you've a small ability to see what you get.

Comment: Tip: You can easily to edit and show the expression tree you want to build in C# Interactive window